# How to add before:spec hook in cypress cucumber framework

Tags: cypress, cypress-cucumber-preprocessor, cypress-custom-commands

```
 getListOfPlans() {
    return new Cypress.Promise((resolve) => {
      usersUtil.getCurrentCompany().then((company) => {
        cy.request({
          method: 'GET',
          url: `${TrainingPlanApi.baseTrainingPlanApiUrl}/company/${company.id}/plan`,
        }).then((resp) => {
          expect(resp.status).to.eq(200);
          cy.wrap(resp.body.data).as('existingTrainingPlans');
          resolve(resp.body.data);
        });
      });
      if (this.environment === 'local') {
        trainingTrainingPlanListPage.visit();
      } else {
        mainMenu.openTrainingPlans();
        trainingPlanApi.getListOfPlans().then((data) => {
          cy.get(`@existingTrainingPlans`).each((planData) => {
            const plan = planData as unknown as TrainingPlan;
            trainingPlanApi.delete(plan.ksuid);
          });
        });
      }
    }) as unknown as Chainable<TrainingPlanRequest>;
```

i need to call the above api function in the before:spec

```
on('before:spec', async (spec) => {
    getListOfPlans
  });
```

but the above doesnt work, not sure how to solve this please

Answer (score -1):

First, you need to link your function to a custom command, in this way:

```
Cypress.Commands.add('getListOfPlans', getListOfPlans)
```

Then, you can invoke that command in your before hook, in this way:

```
Before(() => {
  cy.getListOfPlans()
})
```

**Note**: The function and the custom command should be in the same file, or import the function into the file where the command is declared.

Comment: The question is asking how to run the `before:spec` hook. BTW it's not necessary to create a custom command to call the function.

Comment: My answer responses how to run the before:spec regardless I think it's a good manner to use a custom command as part of the process. And if you have a better answer you better provide it instead of just criticizing.